# What can i change in this code to make it work?

Tags: c, microcontroller, sensors, arduino-uno, atmega32

This C code, Atmel Studio,  is supposed to check pins 2 and 3 on PORTD which is connected to a 4 direction tilt sensor (Up, down, left, right) then lights up 4 different LEDs for each direction. LEDs are connected on PORTB.

code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

#include <util/delay.h>

#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU   16000000UL
#endif




//// define input sensor on PORT D
//
//#define tilt_S1 (PIND&(1<<2))
//#define tilt_S2 (PIND&(1<<3))
//
////define output LEDs on PORT B
//
//#define LED_U (PINB&(1<<0))
//#define LED_D (PINB&(1<<1))
//#define LED_L (PINB&(1<<2))
//#define LED_R (PINB&(1<<3))





int main(void)
{
    DDRD =0x00; //port d as input
    DDRB =0xFF; //port b as out
    
    
    while (1)
    {
        //int pos = GetTiltPos();     //get current sensor position
        
        
        if ( ( (PIND & (1<<2))==0 ) && ((PIND & (1<<3))==0 ) )  //Up (North) [S1=0, S2=0]
        {
            PORTB |=  1<<PINB0;    //up   turn on TOP led only
            PORTB &= ~(1<<PINB1); //down
            PORTB &= ~(1<<PINB2); //left 
            PORTB &= ~(1<<PINB3);  //right
        }
        
        
        else if (((PIND & (1<<2))==1 ) && ((PIND & (1<<3))==0 ))   //Left (West)  [
        {
            PORTB &=  ~(1<<PINB0);    //up   
            PORTB &=  ~(1<<PINB1);    //down
            PORTB |=   1<<PINB2;       //left       turn on LEFT led only
            PORTB &=  ~(1<<PINB3);    //right
        }
        
        else if (((PIND & (1<<2))==0) && ((PIND & (1<<3))==1))    //Right (East)
        {
            PORTB &= (~(1<<PINB0));    //up   
            PORTB &= (~(1<<PINB1));    //down
            PORTB &= (~(1<<PINB2));    //left
            PORTB |=  (1<<PINB3);       //right    turn on RIGHT led only
        }
        else if ( ((PIND & (1<<2))==1 ) && ((PIND & (1<<3))==1 ) )     //Down (South)
        {
            PORTB &= ~(1<<PINB0);      //up   
            PORTB |=   1<<PINB1;         //down    turn on BOTTOM led only
            PORTB &= ~(1<<PINB2);      //left
            PORTB &= ~(1<<PINB3);      //right
        }
        
    }
}

//int GetTiltPos()   //function to determine position of sensor
//{
    //int S1 = 1<<PIND2;
    //int S2 = 1<<PIND3;
    //int R = ((S1<<1)| S2) ;
    //return R;
//
//}
```

i tried defining the LEDs and sensors first, but that didn't work so i tried reading from the pin directly  But that wont work either and I don't understand why. This code results in the upper LED to be always ON.
the sensor used is the 4 direction tilt sensor RPI-1031

Comment: How do we know that the problem is in the software?   What did you find oit when you traced through with your debugger?

Comment: I tried the hardware with another code and it worked. and this code has the same logic, so i assumed the problem is probably the syntax of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `(PIND & (1<<2))==1` will never be true. The result of `(PIND & (1<<2))` will either be 0 or 4 (`1<<2`). An easy way to avoid this issue is to always check for equal or not equal to zero, such as `(PIND & (1<<2)) != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You read from `PINB` instead of **`PIND`** (example: `(PINB & (1<<2))`) - i should be `(PIND & (1<<2))`
2. You do not set the port D as input as `|=` does not not work the way you think

```
DDRD |=0x00; //port d as input
```

This line does nothing. If you want to zero the register you need to:

```
DDRD = 0;
```

or if you only need to zero some of the bits on the register (for example bit 1,3 & 5)

```
DDRD &= ~((1 << 1) || (1 << 3) | (1 << 5));
```

Comment: I tried DDRD=0X00; and DDRB=0XFF; didnt work.

Comment: DDRD = 0 or DDRD |=0?

Comment: @MariamGhanem you read from PINBB instead of PIND

Comment: I tried both DDRD=0 and DDRD|=0

Comment: i think that you are setting all ports in DDRB as output and reading from PINs from output configured  port you should set PINs that you connected your sensor to as INPUT then read from them, for example DDRD = 0x0A pin number 1 and 3 as output all others input. Connect LEDs to output configured and sensor to INPUT configured

Comment: I fixed it and the output is still pinb0 always high (TOP LED)